# Interface Builder + Sprite Strips

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, button, sprite

I'm in the midst of porting a win32 app to cocoa. Wherever possible, I'm using IB, since... well its way easier in every way possible, obviously. One thing is the designer and the win32 dev set up all the button assets on a massive "sprite sheet" such you move around the viewport to determine button state. Similar to how yahoo does CSS sprites on their home page (http://d.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/pa_icons/20100309/spr_apps_us.png)

Can IB be setup to handle this type sprite strip with the default buttons, or are we SOL on this one? I can certainly fire something up programmatically that would do this, but would like to incorporate as much of the default button behavior and selector hookup in IB.

Thoughts?

Josh

Comment: I don't quite get it.. each button has a custom background? Possibly a different one for each button state? And each custom background is part of a large sprite sheet? Say you know that on mouse-down you need to translate the sprite by (0px, -150px) - where are you going to do that?

Comment: Indeed. Well, the css sprite technique utilizes it for both the button background and the button icon - I'm interested in using the default backgrounds from IB NSButtons, and utilizing this technique for the icon only.

I've gone ahead and built the basic button with no icon out in interface builder, then I'm subclassing NSButton to do the heavy lifting for mouseDown, mouseUp, etc. Doesn't seem to be a way to support sprite maps natively in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported in IB because it is really not a Cocoa way of setting button images. I understand why you would use sprites in CSS but in a native program (on any platform) it seems really unnecessary and inefficient.

I honestly think it would be much less work for you to forget about using the sprites. Out of curiosity, are these buttons going to be for standard user interactions, or something more along the line of buttons for a game? If it is for standard user interactions (open file, change font, etc.) then I strongly recommend using the stock buttons as much as possible, although I understand that this might be out of your control. The reason is that the worst ported apps are usually the ones that try to keep visual fidelity with their Windows counterpart.